# AspectJ parameterized types not support for target pointcuts

Tags: java, aspectj, pointcuts

I would like to create a class that pointcuts to methods within the list interface. This seems to work until I add the target(list) to my advice. I would like to view the elements of a list before and after adding to (for example) see what has changed but I cannot seem to pass my list in as I would an object. Here is what I have so far, this does not run with the target(list) but does run without it :

```
pointcut addPointCut() : call(boolean List.add(..));

before(List<Integer> list) : addPointCut() && target(list) {
    System.out.println("testing");
    for(Object i : list) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nándor's answer is correct insofar as he describes the compiler error you see. I want to go a little further and also explain ***why*** you get this error:

First of all, the problem is not directly related to AspectJ but rather to how Java implements generics. Please make yourself familiar with a phenomenon called [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) before you continue to read.

Well, because type erasure is a JVM reality and because `target()` and `this()` are resolved during runtime rather than compile time - you can indirectly conclude this from the fact that both `getTarget()` and `getThis()` are methods of `JoinPoint` rather than `JoinPoint.StaticPart` - what you want to do cannot work and consequently leads to an AspectJ compiler error. The only thing you can do is use `instanceof` in order to dynamically determine what gets added to the target list. The most elegant way to do this is an `if()` pointcut expression.

Here is some sample code:

**Driver application:**

So as to make things a little more interesting we use two types of lists and also two types of `add(..)` calls. The goal should be to only intercept integers to be added to the corresponding list, no matter which signature the `add(..)` method has.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        integers.add(11);
        integers.add(0, 22);
        integers.add(33);

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("foo");
        strings.add(0, "bar");
        strings.add("zot");
    }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.util.List;

@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
public aspect GenericsAspect {
    pointcut addPointCut(List list, Object newElement) :
        !within(GenericsAspect) &&            // avoid stack overflow due to recursion
        call(* List.add(..)) &&               // intercept all calls to List.add
        args(.., newElement) &&               // capture last method parameter
        if(newElement instanceof Integer) &&  // only capture added int/Integer elements
        target(list);                         // target is a List

    before(List list, Object newElement) :
        addPointCut(list, newElement)
    {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> new element = " + newElement);
        for(Object i : list)
            System.out.println("  " + i);

        // Type erasure in action:
        // During runtime there is no such thing as List<Integer>, only a raw List.
        // Thus, we can easily add a String to a list declared as List<Integer>.
        list.add("#" + newElement + "#");
    }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
call(boolean java.util.List.add(Object)) -> new element = 11
call(void java.util.List.add(int, Object)) -> new element = 22
  #11#
  11
call(boolean java.util.List.add(Object)) -> new element = 33
  22
  #11#
  11
  #22#
```

Any further questions?

Answer (score 0):

Using generics in the type `target(...)` or `this(...)` pointcut is not supported and compilation will fail with this error: `parameterized types not supported for this and target pointcuts (erasure limitation)`. Remove the type parameter from the list and it should work as expected.